Ubuntu 24.04 ISSUE
I recently Installed Ubuntu 24.04, Recently I was using 22.04.
now in the newer version lot of applications I use daily are not installing and those that are installing are not opening, what could be the issues? Not all but most.
VS CODE, GitHub-Desktop, Slack etc these are working

For each application that is not working contact the vendor of the app and find out if they support Ubuntu 24.04

@David thanks David

I think you encountered this issue: How to make Balena Etcher work in Ubuntu 24.04?. The workaround fixes not just Etcher, but also other apps.

The conventional wisdom is that is that it is best to wait until the first point release of a new version before committing to it if you have mission critical concerns. The first point release for 24.04.1 is expected to be in August by which time it is expected many of the initial niggles will have been resolved and 3rd party software vendors will have had their own chance to upgrade/amend their software to meet new specifications and requirements.
In my own case, I wait at least until the first point release drops before totally committing to it as my daily driver by which time, I will have fully tested it against any mission critical software on my scratch PC and resolved any problems or found acceptable workarounds.

I understand your point, I also wait and use the Stable release, but I liked the new Version so I got tempted, I use Ubuntu for web dev so most of the things I need are working fine, but if I encounter too many issues I simply may switch back to V 22
